# R: Time series: Difference of arrays returns 0 instead of true difference

Tags: r, time-series

As shown below, I'm trying to subtract TMin1array from Tarray. Does anyone know why the resulting array is returning all 0's? Tarray and TMin1array are of type double.

[image]

Comment: Wondering if R is matching up the rows and doing T - T instead of T  - [T-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user1800340 is right. These seem to be R time series objects. Look at the help page via `?ts`:

```
Class "ts" has a number of methods. In particular arithmetic will attempt to align time axes
```

Example:

```
A1 <- ts(c(1,2,3), start=c(2000,1), end=c(2000,3))
A2 <- ts(c(2,3,4), start=c(2000,2), end=c(2000,4))
 A1-A2
Time Series:
Start = 2001 
End = 2002 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0 0
```

which is exactly what happened to you. Not only does it align the dates, but it deletes all the dates which aren't common to both series. Try converting your time series to vectors first.

```
> as.vector(A1)-as.vector(A2)
[1] -1 -1 -1
```